# How to style or customize React-admin Alert Dialog?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, alert, react-admin

[reac-admin alert dialog example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnCUd.png)

I'm developing an admin using React-admin. 
I'm trying do style the alert dialog that shows errors, warnings and success message in the page. 
For example I would like to set some css into this alert like z-index, background-color...
I already saw the docs in Material UI how to customize components, but the problem is that into react-admin this component seams to be native and I couldn't find into react-admin docs any information about my question. 
I appreciate some help.
Regards

Comment: Use the devtools to inspect the classnames and ids of the elements you are looking to style. Then, overwrite them in a local css file with whatever attributes you want

Comment: The problem is that this alert come without id and the classes show up always with different numbers. Seams to be some javascript that create the classes name

Comment: The classnames may not always be exactly the same, but there should be some common feature that you can find and use as a selector. For example, it could always be the third child of some parent div. Thats just an example, but there are many possible selectors

Comment: I see. I'm gonna try something like this and share the results...

Comment: In the future please consider providing us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How can I provide a reproducible example of a native code that I don't know where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the notification component, as described below:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#notifications

The original component:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/layout/Notification.tsx